# Move PictureBox location with threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, panel, picturebox

I am creating a catching game where eggs are dropped. In my Panel subclass, I have this code

```
public void startGame()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(game));
        t.Start();
    }

private void game()
    {
        bool run = true;

        int level = 1;

        while (run)
        {
            Egg egg = dropper.selectEgg();
            int speed = dropper.getSpeed(level);

            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { 
                    this.Controls.Add(egg);
                    egg.setInitialLocation(dropper.selectPosition());

                    int x = egg.Location.X;
                    int y = egg.Location.Y;

                    while (y <= 1000)
                    {
                        egg.setCurrentLocation(x, dropper.drop(egg, speed));
                        y = egg.Location.Y;
                    }
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                this.Controls.Add(egg);
                egg.setInitialLocation(dropper.selectPosition());

                int x = egg.Location.X;
                int y = egg.Location.Y;

                while (y <= 1000)
                {
                    egg.setCurrentLocation(x, dropper.drop(egg, speed));
                    y = egg.Location.Y;
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
    }
```

Egg is a subclass of PictureBox and I want to change its location on loop so it looks like the eggs are dropping. I use the EggDropper subclass with this method:

```
public int drop(Egg egg, int speed)
    {

        int y = egg.Location.Y;
        y += speed;

        return y;
    }
```

but somehow, I don't see any of the Egg objects dropping. I'm guessing it is a problem with the thread accessing the PictureBox subclass? But I can't seem to find any solution online.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `drop` on the main UI thread. This quickly runs a loop that increments `y` until it is > 1000. The UI cannot update while this loop is running, so all you will see is the egg at the bottom of the screen when `drop` finishes and the UI can run its message loop again.

The solution is to change `drop` to just decrement `y` once and then return control to your `game` loop. You will have to move the `y <= 1000` check to this loop as well.

---

**UPDATE:**

Your "step" is an iteration of the `while( run )` loop - that's where you have the `Sleep` to control the animation. You must only make one update to `egg.Location.Y` on each "step" - don't run the whole `while( y <= 1000 )` loop on each "step".

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused. In drop(), I just set it to return y position. And in game(), that is where I added egg.setCurrentLocation(). It is still not working.

Comment: I get it now. I will update the code again later with the answer. Thank you so much!